# Symfony Test Error on Gitlab CI

Tags: php, symfony, gitlab-ci

I dont have erron on my test local pc . But ı have error on Gitlab CI.

**Error:** 
**/register -> 200** status code on my pc . 
**/register -> 500** status code on Gitlab CI

Test Code:

```
   public  function testRegister()
    {
        $client=static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/register');
        $status= $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
        $this->assertEquals(200,$status);
    }
```

Routing:

```
register:
    path: /register
    defaults: {_controller: "AppBundle:User:register"}
```

Comment: Please check your log file to find out what error stands behind the 500 response code.

Comment: How can ı check log on Gitlab CI?

Comment: The logs are in app/logs, but you'll have to access the server using SSH to take a look at them.

Comment: thank you for comments :) ı solve it . there is 'https' in my page . This is cause ssl error. I remove it  then no errors.
/register -> 200 status code on Gitlab CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the logs directory as artefact. And use `when:always` then you can view them in gitlab.

When you provide the logs I may can help you further.

Comment: thank you for comment :) ı solve it . there is 'https' in my page . This is cause ssl error. I remove it then no errors. /register -> 200 status code on Gitlab CI

Comment: @BurhanYılmaz I came here with the same problem but I don't know how to do it. Any way you can expand your answer?

Comment: @JorgeeFG What is your server ? (ubuntu,debian,windows...). My server is debian jesie . solve -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44265000/6741410

Comment: @BurhanYılmaz It is based on Ubuntu... this had to be a problem between composer server and gitlab, because I ran the task some hours after and it worked good. But I did find what you were talking about Artefacts