# Gitlab CI Ssl Error

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, symfony-3.2

I dont have error on my pc.But ı have a error ssl on gitlabci. How is it solve this problem ?

Server:**Debian**

Error Output:

```
  [Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception]                                               
  Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename"; AWS HTTP error: Error creating resource: [m  
  essage] fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:   
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify   
  failed                                                                       
  [file] /builds/burhan/blutron/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHa  
  ndler.php                                                                    
  [line] 312                                                                   
  [message] fopen(): Failed to enable crypto                                   
  [file] /builds/burhan/blutron/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHa  
  ndler.php                                                                    
  [line] 312                                                                   
  [message] fopen(https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename): failed to open stream: operation failed                      
  [file] /builds/burhan/blutron/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHa  
  ndler.php                                                                    
  [line] 312
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.gitlab-ci.yml Files

```
image:

before_script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install -y ca-certificates
  - ....
  - ....
```

I solved it update and ca-certificates .